# How to test while loop code using jest and nodejs

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm having a hard time doing some test on while loop using jest. This is the code I want to test but don't know how to do it.

```
const SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256')

class Block {
    constructor(index, timestamp, data, prevHash = "") {
        this.index = index
        this.timestamp = timestamp
        this.data = data
        this.prevHash = prevHash
        this.hash = this.calculateHash()
        this.nonce = 0
    }

    calculateHash() {
        return SHA256(this.index + this.prevHash + this.timestamp + JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.nonce).toString()
    }

    mineBlock(difficulty) {
        while(this.hash.substring(0, difficulty) !== Array(difficulty + 1).join('0')) {
            this.nonce++
            this.hash = this.calculateHash()
        }

    }
}

module.exports = Block
```

This is what I've done so far

```
const Block = require('../block')

const BlockClass = new Block()

describe('Block Class', () => {
    it('constructor', () => {
        const obj = new Block(1, 2, 3, 4, 0)
        expect(obj.index).toBe(1)
        expect(obj.timestamp).toBe(2)
        expect(obj.data).toBe(3)
        expect(obj.prevHash).toBe(4)
        expect(obj.nonce).toBe(0)
    })
})

describe('hash', () => {
    it('should be string', () => {
        expect(typeof BlockClass.calculateHash()).toBe('string')
    })
})
```

I'm pretty new with jest and unit testing and I find it really nice skills to have.

Comment: If the function does not return a value, you have to test the whole component. Please edit this question with your full code.

Comment: alright, will edit the question

Comment: Please mention what function you want to test?

Comment: `Array(difficulty + 1).join('0') === '0'.repeat(difficulty)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
const Block = require('../block')

describe('mineBlock', () => {
    let block = new Block()
    it('should do <something>', () => {
        block.mineBlock(5)

        expect(block.nonce).toBe('<something>')
        expect(block.hash).toBe('<something>')
    })
})
```

Please replace `<something>` with real values you want.

Comment: Please mark this as correct if this is the correct answer.

Comment: I'm pretty new with jest really can't tell what to replace on <something>
this is basically what I want 
    `this.nonce++`
    `this.hash = this.calculateHash()`

Comment: It should be the output value that you expect. You will have to read about assertions in Jest. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Comment: yes but If i do something like this `expect(block.hash).toBe(block.calculatehash())` I'm receiving error that expected and received does not matched 4047341442cc4769ef0e819fdd6376476e99210de7e18e9aaca9aa8b0289fa32
    + 0000f87392df61aa818068120c143a425b2926e89498cf553dcd585030312ca6`

Comment: block.calculatehash() generates a different hash. That is why the test is failing. First, you have to do is decrypt the hash. Then you will be able to assert with the decrypted value.